# I want to know how to read the image map generated by galen framework report for layout testing. What do the colors orange, green, red mean?

Tags: image, selenium, layout, mapping, galen

I am comparing 2 UI screens using Galen Layout testing framework in which a report is generated with image comparison map. I want to understand what doe these colors on the map in the attached image mean.

[image: Image Comparison Map generated by Galen framework using selenium for layout testing]

Answer (score 2):

These Color code represents the tolerance value. Green pixel  represents tolerance of comparison is less. Red represent high tolerance mismatch. Orange more tolerance than yellow and less than Red. you can find details in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bheFQfEGR6U